# Sending bulk email using Laravel queue make page loading

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I want to send bulk emails to all users. I have around 200 users in my database. The email will send once the admin submits the form. once the admin submits the form, the page takes a long time to process and the page keeps loading. I have tried to implement a queue job after realizing the backend stop process after all emails have been sent. The result after implementing the queue process is the same as the old process. The page takes a longer time to load.
Below are my codes:

Controller:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $status = $request->input('status');

    Duration::where('id', $id)
    ->update([
        'active' => $request['status'],
    ]);

    $data = [
        'status' =>$status,
    ];
    
    $job = (new \App\Jobs\SendEmail($data))->delay(now()->addSeconds(2)); 

    dispatch($job);

    return back()->with('message','Duration has been updated'); 
}
```

Jobs codes:

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\User;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\DurationMail;

public function handle()
{
    $users=User::where('active','=','1')->get();

    $input['status'] = $this->data['status'];

    foreach ($users as $user) 
    {
        $emails = $user->email;
        $names = $user->name;

        $data = array(
            'name' => $names,
            'status' => $input['status'],
        );

        try{
            Mail::to($emails)->send(new DurationMail($data));
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect()->route('duration.index')->with('success','Duration created successfully');
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how can I make the system load at a minimal time? I'm afraid, if I keep using this function, my server will be crash. Thank you.

Comment: is your .env file setted up correctly? Check the param QUEUE_CONNECTION.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#driver-prerequisites

Comment: @Jack yup, I have set up correctly but when i run the queue, it not send email and show error:

Comment: `The process "C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.7-Win32-vc15-x64\php.exe artisan queue:work --once --name=default --queue=default --backoff=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=1" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#timeout

Comment: Or, explode the list in separate jobs, and execute it one by one, or batch, or whatever.